# Find indices of particular items in the list using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of integers from 1 to 20. I want the indices of items which are greater than 10 using linq. Is it possible to do with linq?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the overload of `Select` which includes the index:

```
var highIndexes = list.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
                      .Where(z => z.value > 10)
                      .Select(z => z.index);
```

The steps in turn:

- Project the sequence of values into a sequence of value/index pairs
- Filter to only include pairs where the value is greater than 10
- Project the result to a sequence of indexes

Comment: @jon Skeet thanks for your reply Is it possible to retrive two columns (like we retrieve from database) using linq

Comment: @ratty, It can be done by select, Read 101 linq samples (google it) to understand.

Comment: @saeed ,do u know any particular link for that

Comment: @ratty: Did you try searching, as per Saeed's suggestion?

Comment: @jon skeet i found that Thank you for you and saeed

Comment: @unmesh i found the answer from your posted . but i found that before your post

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static List<int> FindIndexAll(this List<int> src, Predicate<int> value)
    {
        List<int> res = new List<int>();
        var idx = src.FindIndex(x=>x>10);           
        if (idx!=-1) {
        res.Add(idx);
         while (true)
         {
            idx = src.FindIndex(idx+1, x => x > 10);
            if (idx == -1)
                break;
            res.Add(idx);
         }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Usage

```
        List<int>  test= new List<int>() {1,10,5,2334,34,45,4,4,11};
        var t = test.FindIndexAll(x => x > 10);
```

Comment: This looks a pretty complicated way of going about it. If I wasn't going to use LINQ, I'd probably just loop through myself. Note that your code will currently fail if there are *no* entries matching the predicate - it will put -1 in the list.

Comment: @ramesh thank you for your reply by the by i am also chennai guy

Comment: @ramesh give your mail id if u like if i have any doubt i will conduct through that

Comment: @ratty, you can get better answers here in SO than from me. :) my id is raam_kimi at hot mail dot com...