# Creating a select list from an array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, list, ienumerable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to find the index particular items in the list using linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374237/how-to-find-the-index-particular-items-in-the-list-using-linq)

I am trying to create a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from an array of strings.

```
string[] months = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };

model.month = months
        .Select(r => new SelectListItem{Text = r, Value = ???});
```

Is there a way to access their index within this query?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use overloaded [Enumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) method:

```
model.month = months
    .Select((r,index) => new SelectListItem{Text = r, Value = index.ToString()});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reference. As a note, `Value` must be of type string so `Value = index.ToString()` would be correct

Answer (score 5):

Try with [`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx).

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form by incorporating
>   the element's index.

```
model.month = months
        .Select((r, i) => new SelectListItem{Text = r, Value = i.ToString()});
```

Answer (score 2):

Jeff this should work for you based on the example on the link that lila G posted

```
string[] months = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };
var query = months.Select((r, index) => new  { Text = r, Value = index });
```

Screen shot of what it looks like in the Debugger

[image]